# Unknown protocol in Protege while importing OWL

Tags: java, owl, protege

I am using Protege 5.5. When I open an existing owl file with something like this,

```
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.org/eg/Robot.owl">
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="package://example/owl/blah.owl"/>
</owl:Ontology>
```

Protege correctly resolves the imports even with IRIs starting with `package://`.

```
Imported ontology document package://example/owl/blah.owl was resolved to Optional[file:/home/user/owl/blah.owl] by the ontology catalog.
```

But when I am creating a new OWL file and try to do a manual "direct import", I get an error:

```
Malformed URL: Unknown protocol: package 
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: package

java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: package
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:627) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1089) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.canLoad(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:159) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.actualParse(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1256) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1215) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1115) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadImports(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1833) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.makeLoadImportRequest(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1871) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$TPImportsHandler.handleTriple(TripleHandlers.java:1651) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.TripleHandlers$HandlerAccessor.handleStreaming(TripleHandlers.java:278) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.OWLRDFConsumer.statementWithResourceValue(OWLRDFConsumer.java:1554) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.statementWithResourceValue(RDFParser.java:370) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.EmptyPropertyElement.startElement(StartRDF.java:236) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.PropertyElementList.startElement(StartRDF.java:658) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.startElement(RDFParser.java:201) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:145) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.semanticweb.owlapi.rdf.rdfxml.parser.RDFXMLParser.parse(RDFXMLParser.java:73) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.loadOWLOntology(OWLOntologyFactoryImpl.java:221) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.actualParse(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1262) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1215) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:1172) [owlapi-osgidistribution.jar:4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.ontology.imports.AddImportsStrategy.loadImportsInternal(AddImportsStrategy.java:103) [protege-editor-owl.jar:na]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.ui.ontology.imports.AddImportsStrategy.lambda$addImportsInOtherThread$1(AddImportsStrategy.java:64) [protege-editor-owl.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown protocol: package
    at org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.parseURL(URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.java:373) ~[org.apache.felix.main.jar:na]
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:622) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

I have tried editing the `catalog-v001.xml` file and all the entries for imports with `package://` have been redirected to the physical location of the owl files, but the error persists.

Comment: `package://` is not a valid protocol, you should add the file location URL there.

Comment: `package://` does gets redirected to file location when I open an existing `.owl`. The problem arises only when I do I direct import.